# Comparing values between columns in Pandas Dataframe generates "Cannot index with multidimensional key" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    Date                Time      A
0   2019-06-20 07:00:00 70000   -322
1   2019-06-20 07:05:00 70500   -439
2   2019-06-20 07:10:00 71000   -528
3   2019-06-20 07:15:00 71500   -606
4   2019-06-20 07:20:00 72000   -642
5   2019-06-20 07:25:00 72500   -663
6   2019-06-20 07:30:00 73000   -620
7   2019-06-20 07:35:00 73500   -561
8   2019-06-20 07:40:00 74000   -592
9   2019-06-20 07:45:00 74500   -614
10  2019-06-20 07:50:00 75000   -630
11  2019-06-20 07:55:00 75500   -719
12  2019-06-20 08:00:00 80000   -613
13  2019-06-20 08:05:00 80500   -127
14  2019-06-20 08:10:00 81000   -235
```

and I want to compare values from column 'A' based on two time values.
Let's say I'd like to know if A at time 7:20 is smaller than at 7:40
I tried it this way, but i get an error:

```
df.A.loc[df.loc[df['Time'] == 72000]] < df.A.loc[df.loc[df['Time'] == 74000]]

error: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` as follows and then `.iloc[0]` to get the value to compare.

```
df.loc[df['Time'] == 72000, 'A'].iloc[0] < df.loc[df['Time'] == 74000, 'A'].iloc[0]
```

output:

```
True
```